# Is it possible to disable zsh 'select' style's need to hit return in order to select an option?

Tags: zsh

Visually, I love the selection menu provided by the completion style:

```sh
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select;
```

However, having to press return to leave the selection menu is driving me crazy. I would much rather that pressing return would immediately run the active prompt.

Since zsh fills the selection immediately to the active prompt, I hoped to find a way to disable this extra return key-press, but I have been unable to find anything related online or in the man pages.
If it isn't so straightforward as "I just missed the page and I'm an idiot," where can I go to  learn how to customize this aspect of zsh?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the return is necessary to exit the menu, but the result is that the selection is added to the command line without immediately executing it. It might be possible to change that (history expansion, for example, can be configured to immediately execute the expanded command without giving you an opportunity to edit the command line first), but I'm not sure that makes sense for command completion, as it would only be useful for commands that take no arguments.

Comment: I suppose that mostly makes sense.

Considering the commands which would require an extra argument though: I don't have to press return once that selection is chosen; I can just press space and immediately continue typing arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zshmodules(1)'s "The zsh/complist module"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fcomplist-Module) could help. It is pointed in the [zshcompsys(1)'s "Standard styles" 'menu' entry](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-menu_002c-completion-style).

```
zmodload zsh/complist
# Below overrides default '^M' keybind.
bindkey -M complist '^M' .accpet-line
```

Here is a descripton of zsh manual at the very end of the zsh/complist module entry:

> All movement functions wrap around at the edges; any other zle function not listed leaves menu selection and executes that function.  It is possible to make widgets in the above list do the same by using the form of the widget with a `.` in front. For example, the widget `.accept-line` has the effect of leaving menu selection and accepting the entire command line.
>
> --- [zshmodules(1), menu selection, the zsh/complist module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fcomplist-Module)

Comment: I don't think I realized the `zsh/complist` module provides that functionality! Thank you very much :)